# Previews of matlab figures in Windows explorer (utility to set an image as the thumbnail for another file)

Tags: windows, matlab, com, preview, matlab-figure

Has anyone come up with a way to make thumbnail type previews for matlab figures in windows?

I'm getting tired of saving a .png along with the .fig file just so I know what was in it.

A useful helper for this would be a command line utility for windows that can be provided with an image file and told to use that as the basis for the preview for a given file.

I could write a helper function in matlab that saved the .fig, made a temporary image file, then pushed that into the thumbnail using the command line utility.

Comment: Could a single wrapper function (or batch file) be written that's assigned as the thumbnailer for a specific type, but actually calls an external (matlab) program to produce a temporary image, which then becomes the thumbnail?  I'd like to be able to do this with python scripts, too. http://superuser.com/questions/267392/how-would-i-create-a-thumbnailer-for-windows-7-explorer

Comment: Yes, I think that's a way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a function in C++ that tells Windows how to generate thumbnails from your file. 
[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144067%28VS.85%29.aspx) explains about it. Check out the section about `Thumbnail Image handler`. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774612%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the function that you will need to implement.

From what I managed to understand, the procedure is this:

1. Write a in-process COM server (DLL) that implements [IThumbnailProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface
2. Put the DLL file somewhere on your computer.
3. Write an entry to the registry, by using the procedure described in [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144067%28VS.85%29.aspx).

That still leaves you with the problem of thumbnail extraction from `.fig` file. As far as I know, `fig` files are nothing but `mat` files. I am fairly sure that it is possible.

You will need a custom save function for all figures. It will print a thumbnail of the image (by using the `print` command), and save it inside the figure.

I know that it isn't much information, but it can help you to get started. You might as well ask someone who is highly proficient in `COM` technology for more help. Thus, I recommend adding a `COM` tag to the question.

**Edit(1)** - I've found a [good tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/830/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens) on the subject:

Comment: That sounds like a start. Extracting the image in the first place is easy as I can save that at the same time I save the fig (which I do now anyway). I just need to tell windows to use the image as the thumbnail.

Comment: [this article](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/fig-files-format/) might help on getting the data out of the fig

Comment: Yeah, that's a good tutorial. I might spend some time next week trying to make something that works.